# Matlab engine: License Checkout Failed

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-engine

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting a `License Checkout Failed` when running Matlab Engine from Java.  I have this very simple Matlab script:

```
function [] = Test()
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
y = [ 4 6 8 5 3];
 mdl = fitlm(x,y);
 mdl
end
```

`fitlm` requires the **Statistics_Toolbox**.  I can run the above script without issues from the Matlab (version *2019b*) desktop application.  But when I run the same script through the Matlab engine I get

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mathworks.engine.MatlabExecutionException: Test()
    at com.mathworks.engine.FutureResult.get(FutureResult.java:64)
    at com.mathworks.engine.MatlabEngine.eval(MatlabEngine.java:349)
    at xxxxxxx.main(Test.kt:11)
Caused by: com.mathworks.mvm.exec.MvmRuntimeException: License checkout failed.
License Manager Error 0

Troubleshoot this issue by visiting: 
https://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2019b/0

Diagnostic Information:
Feature: Statistics_Toolbox 
License path: C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2019b_licenses;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\licenses\license.dat;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\licenses\network.lic 
Licensing error: 0,0.
    ... 3 more
com.mathworks.mvm.exec.MvmRuntimeException: License checkout failed.
License Manager Error 0
```

Any ideas what could be different about the license checkout process between the desktop app and the Engine that would cause this?  My only thought might be that my company has a proxy server and was wondering if the desktop app knew about proxy settings that the engine doesn't.

Comment: It says right there in the error message: “Troubleshoot this issue by visiting: 
https://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2019b/0”.

Comment: Try clicking the link.  Did you find it helpful?  Didn't think so.

Comment: That’s bad. The next thing to do is contact support directly: https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us.html